# Mvc-infinite-scroll package null session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement this [pakage](https://github.com/philoushka/Mvc-Infinite-Scroll-Grid)

After I load the data from the DB, I store it like this:

```
Session["reservations"] = futureReservations.ToDictionary(x => custIndex++, x => x);
```

Then I am trying to get only the data I need for the current page:

```
public Dictionary<int, Restaurants> GetRecordsForPage(int pageNum)
        {
            Dictionary<int, Restaurants> reservations = (Session["reservations"] as Dictionary<int, Restaurants>);

            int from = (pageNum * RecordsPerPage);
            int to = from + RecordsPerPage;


            return reservations
                .Where(x => x.Key > from && x.Key <= to)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        }
```

The problem is that the `reservations` variable stays null, even if the session info is correct. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: What is `custIndex` and why are you storing this as a dictionary?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is just a variable that counts the entries `int custIndex = 1;`. I used it as in the demo code of the package.

Comment: Sorry, makes no sense. Does `futureReservations` contain all the items in the collection. If so just store the it in `Session` and use `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to filter the item you want to return

Comment: If you store the collection as `Session["reservations"] = futureReservations`, then in the method use return reservations.Skip(from).Take(RecordsPerPage); to return `IEnumerable<T>`, but unless the collection of `futureReservations` is specific to a user, it should be stored in `MemoryCache`